# weblogic jdbc Datasource error BEA-001131 Closed Connection

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I have Installed weblogic 10.3.5 with jrocket 1.6.0_33. Oracle Fusion Middleware 11.1.1 on Windows Environment. On database side I have Oracle database 11gR2 RAC environment with Two instance on Linux Environment. I have created

```
GRIDLINK DataSource with XA DRIVERS.                
NAME: test
JNDI: jdbc/testDS
```

NOTE: I have used SCAN IP for this DataSource configuration.

```
FAN ENABLED checked.
ONS HOST : scan-ip:6200
Not using "ONS Wallet".
```

DataSource was created successfully. Testing is done. Now when I start Application for 1st time and Click on any TAB, The Managed Server through some error on its console screen.

```
<error> <JDBC> <BEA-001131> <Received an exception when closing a cached statement for the pool "test": SQLRecoverableException: Closed Coonection.>
```

What should I do to resolve this error.

Comment: You really should enable those debug flags. It seems like a problem in the application, not in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

You should discover what's really happening when you enable debug on the weblogic instance in question. Here are the flags you can setup on server start as arguments.

```
-Dweblogic.debug.DebugJDBCRAC=true 
-Dweblogic.debug.DebugJDBCONS=true
-Dweblogic.debug.DebugJDBCUCP=true
```

Comment: I have made some changes in weblogic console. now i'm not getting the ERROR <BEA-001131>. but now i'm getting new error ADF_FACES-60097 with ADF_FACES-60096. this error occurs when I login with two new session on same machine and when I logout from 1 session the other session through this error.