# Oracle ADF DataSource for RAC environment

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

I have environment of Oracle database 11gR2 Single Instance on linux, Weblogic 10.3.5 on Windows. I have running ADF Application with single instance database. The Connection between Database and Application is configured by using Generic DataSource "MyAppDS".
On Other side i Have Configured new RAC Database environment with same Application. the Connection between RAC database and Application is configured by using GridLink DataSource. the Confusion is about the JDBC/MyAppDS. Is this should be same or different for RAC. Should the Developer have to create new connection string for RAC database.? kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recommend using JDBC Thin driver with Oracle RAC.  Most of our customers are using JDBC Thin driver. Active Grid Link is the correct datasource to use with WLS.  Sample RAC URL is as shown below.  Always use SCAN for better manageability purposes.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =
(CONNECT_TIMEOUT= 90)  (RETRY_COUNT=20)(RETRY_DELAY=3)
(ADDRESS_LIST =
  (LOAD_BALANCE=on)
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST=primary-scan)(PORT=1521)))
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
  (LOAD_BALANCE=on)
  ( ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST=secondary-scan)(PORT=1521)))       
  (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME = gold-cloud)))
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you help me about this ERROR. what is the cause of this error. 
<JDBC> <BEA-001131> <Received an exception when closing a cached statement for the pool "MyApp": sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Coonection.>. it appear continually on ManagedServer console.

Comment: kindly check My Question related to ERROR BEA-001131 Closed Connection by clicking this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272785/weblogic-jdbc-datasource-error-bea-001131-closed-connection)

Comment: I have made some changes in weblogic console. now i'm not getting the ERROR <BEA-001131>. but now i'm getting new error ADF_FACES-60097 with ADF_FACES-60096. this error occurs when I login with two new session on same machine and when I logout from 1 session the other session through this error.

Answer (score 0):

The JNDI name can be the same, as long as the other one pointing to the single instance change from JDBC/MyAppDS to something else, let's say JDBC/MyAppDSOld.

The URL should be something like the following:

```
jdbc:oracle:oci:@(DESCRIPTION = (LOAD_BALANCE = ON) (FAILOVER = ON)
(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.10.10.10)(PORT = 1521))
(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.10.10.11)(PORT = 1522))
(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = xxxx) (FAILOVER_MODE =(TYPE = SELECT)(METHOD = BASIC)(RETRIES = 180)(DELAY = 2))))
```

The Developer should use the GridLink for RAC Datasource type when creating the connection, to take advantage of Oracle ONS, TAF and Load Balancing to multiple database instances.

For a more detailed information on transactions, XA, etc. Take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/jdbc_admin/oracle_rac.html#wp1082519).

Hope it helps !

Comment: As you said the developers are using GridLink Datasource. In url they are using SCAN IP. for example,
jdbc:oracle:thin:@{scan-listener-host}:{scan-listener-port}/{service-name}

Comment: when we configured GridLink Datasource, on ManagedServer console some error accrued like : <error> <JDBC> <BEA-001131> <Received an exception when closing a cached statement for the pool "MyApp": sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Coonection.>

Comment: as you see I am using JDBC:ORACLE:THIN, and you said JDBC:ORACLE:OCI. If I use OCI instead of THIN, should I have to Install Oracle Client 11g on application server??

Comment: you could swap OCI to thin.... OCI is faster, but thin is adjustable to most use cases. Also, if you have setup SCAN no RAC side, stick with it. It will deliver connection affinity and load balancing as well.

Comment: kindly check My Question related to ERROR BEA-001131 Closed Connection by clicking this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272785/weblogic-jdbc-datasource-error-bea-001131-closed-connection)